# Angular 4 SystemJS vs Angular CLI

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am working on an Angular 4.X project and using the SystemJS approach. When I started the project, Angular CLI was in beta version so I used the SyatemJS approach to setup the project. Can anyone here tell me --

1. What are the pros and cons if I use SystemJS over Angular CLI ?
2. Is CLI the recommended way by Angular (I have not read it anywhere honestly)?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `systemjs` is a module loader. `angular cli` is a command line interface for angular. You are comparing apples to oranges. `CLI the recommended way by Angular` <= I do not believe it is.

Comment: `I do not believe it is`  ^--- although you can find it on the same angular.io site domain and github repo so maybe it is. I am not sure why it would matter though (if it is recommended or not stated).

Answer (score 2):

1. What are the pros and cons if I use SystemJS over Angular CLI ?

   > You are comparing apples to oranges. Angular CLI is a tool that helps setting your project up. Though you could make an argument that the cli uses webpack so perhaps you could look up comparisons between webpack and systemjs?
2. Is CLI the recommended way by Angular (I have not read it anywhere honestly)?

   > Yes, even their own tutorials on angular.io strongly recommend the use of the cli.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 2 questions, just take a look at the tutorial "QuickStart" of the official angular site : [Angular QuickStart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)
But you can do with your own Webpack config while respecting the Style Guide for easier to maintain. [Angular - Webpack: An Introduction](https://angular.io/guide/webpack)